# Inno Setup: Disabling components based on PC architecture

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup with two components: one for 32-bit machines and one for 64-bit. These will run on XP/Vista/Win7.

```
[Components]
Name: Bin/32; Description: 32-bit; Types: full; Flags: dontinheritcheck
Name: Bin/64; Description: 64-bit; Types: full; Flags: dontinheritcheck
```

Currently:

- Both Components are ticked by default when running the installer.

What I want is:

- An appropriate default (i.e. either 32-bit or 64-bit ticked) depending on the user's machine.
- Greying out the inappropriate Component would be a bonus too.

What I've found so far is:

- That I probably want to use Pascal in the [Code] section.
- The IsWin64 function
- That I might want to use an Event for this, but I can't find anything related to my needs yet.

P.S. Unfortunately I'm not able to have separate installers per architecture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can check the `C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\Examples`  folder for examples about how install a program for different architectures using a single installer.

check these files

- 64BitThreeArch.iss
- 64BitTwoArch.iss
- 64Bit.iss

you can use something like this

```
[Components]
Name: Bin_32; Description: 32-bit; Types: full; Check: IsX86; Flags: dontinheritcheck
Name: Bin_64; Description: 64-bit; Types: full; Check: IsX64; Flags: dontinheritcheck

[Code]
function IsX64: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Is64BitInstallMode and (ProcessorArchitecture = paX64);
end;

function IsX86: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Is64BitInstallMode=false) and (ProcessorArchitecture = paX86);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for leading me the Examples folder.

Unfortunately that doesn't work for me as that's switching on a per-file basis; I'm looking for a per-component basis. Like some sort of 'Check' functionality for Components maybe.

Comment: Thanks. I had to add the following in the [Setup] to make it work: ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64 ia64

Comment: also works when adding installers for both 32 and 64 bits inside your installer, and you want to run only one depending on the architecture.